# SQLCompare generate only diff script

Tags: sql-server-2008, redgate, sqlcompare, tarantino

Is it possible to generate only diff script using SQLCompare from Red Gate SQl Compare?

In our database sync scenario we will use SQLCompare to generate diff script and will use Tarantino for applying scripts. I've played a little with sqlcompare but not found a way to generate only diff script, without sync databases.

Thanks

Comment: Found this link from red-gate site: http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=12270 
seams to be an issue

Comment: How are you getting on with Tarantino as a framework to manage your migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should install this [patch](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=11077)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer with SQL Compare command-line is to use the /sf: argument to specify an output file and do not specify /sync. But it appears you are possibly running into some other issue which is not described here.